# Python3: Format SOME MYSQL warnings and write ALL to file

Tags: python-3.x, warnings, stdout, pymysql

We have a script that handles data-import. Now that most of the data is properly sanitized we want to focus on fine-tuning the MYSQL backend. This backend is in some cases to rigidly defined (i.e. strings are longer than the varchar allows ...). Since we have new data on a weekly basis we want to log it weekly so that we can use that log to check the data-source and if necessary modify the backend.

For this the importscript needs to be modified slightly:

1. None-1366 MYSQL-warnings need to be suppressed and pretty printed (OK)
2. All MYSQL-warnings need to be written to a log file (OK)
3. Hide the default error notice on import, because this floods the terminal with 1366 warnings. (NOT ok)

The code I have now is (This is only a small part out of a larger script):

```
    into_file_operation = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s/%s.csv' INTO TABLE %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r';" %(folder, name, name)

    #warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    cursor.execute(into_file_operation)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close

    warnings = conn.show_warnings()
    for w in warnings:
        if w[1] != 1366:
            pprint(w, width=100, depth=2)       ##PPRINT non-1366 errors
        else:
            print(str(w[1]), end='\r')    #this can be turned into pass later.
        errorfile.write(str(w)+"\n")        #write ALL to file
        errorfile.flush()

    errorfile.write("\n")
    errorfile.write("********* DONE TABLE **********")
    errorfile.write("\n")
    errorfile.flush()
```

This meets the first two demands, yet it still outputs the very long warnings to the console - which we want to get rid off:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:166: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'y1' at row 126") result = self._query(query)
```

and errors like 1265 can be shown, but need to be pretty printed. With the current code, these get printed twice (first time, the long warning, second time a formatted warning using PrettyPrint)

I think that my next step would be to do something with the STDOUT, yet whatever I tried, I keep ending up with an empty database. I've also tried to use the filter with the ignore parameter, yet then I don't get any warnings at all - which defeats the purpose of having the log.